# UICollectionViewCell Spacing is set to 0 but still have spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to make the spacing between my cells = 0

Example of desired result:

[image]

What I currently have (iPhone 6):

[image]

My code:

```
- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)setCollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    //iphone5 100
    //iphone6 118
    layout.itemSize             = CGSizeMake(118, 118);
    layout.footerReferenceSize  = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

    layout.sectionInset            = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing      = 0.0;

    return layout;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

What I have on IB:

[image]

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your cellsize and imageview size if you didn't set. you have to set your imageview's constraint fit with cell.

replace

```
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(118, 118);
```

with

```
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width /3, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width /3);
```

I set screensize because i assume your collectionview is fit to screen width. replace it with your collectionview size.

Because you are trying to show 3 cells but you set fix width for your item. so just update your cell size. Because in different screen your collectionview widht will be change so you should update your cell size also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still give me the same result. spacing is still there

Comment: @tnylee then maybe you didn't set your imageview's constraint.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I changed the size of the image to be the same as the cell.

Answer (score 3):

It says it is the **minimum spacing** between items, **not** a fixed spacing. The `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` always tries to set as many items on a row as possible.

You should make the width of your `UICollectionViewCells` dynamic and calculate them based on the size of the `UICollectionView`.

So, for example. If you want 3 cells on a row, divide the width of the `UICollectionView` by 3 and you should have the width of the cell. This takes a bit of experimentation with the values though.

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue today, a few pixels inserted between cells, It may cause by Decimal precision being lost, like 340 divide 7, it can not get an integer.
multiple times plus will cause a one-pixel difference.